# How to retrieve specific id from JSON tree

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I can print the `sub_category` and `products` in the tableView and it is working fine but I couldn't print for specific detail for id, for example how can I print the details for `products_id`=`213` to get `name`,`image`,`model`?

My table view looks like this [categories>name] then [sub_category>name] then I need the selected products_id `name`,`image`,`model`

I'm using segue

My JSON:

```
{"categories":[
{"category_id":"100","name":"Shop By Room","sub_category":[
{"category_id":"72","name":"BEDROOM","sub_category":0,"product_total":"11","products":[
{"product_id":"138","name":"Jewellery  Holder","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"28223","sku":"1050426","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"6","stock_status":"In Stock","image":"data\/bedroom\/28223-clear.jpg","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"18"},
{"product_id":"139","name":"Jewellery Holder","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"28223","sku":"1050507","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"6","stock_status":"In Stock","image":"data\/bedroom\/28223-green.jpg","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"6"},
{"product_id":"136","name":"Mirror","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"28225","sku":"1050509","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"6","stock_status":"Out Of Stock","image":"data\/bedroom\/28225-green.jpg","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"6"},
{"product_id":"137","name":"Mirror","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"28225","sku":"1050430","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"6","stock_status":"In Stock","image":"data\/bedroom\/28225-clear.jpg","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"6"},
{"product_id":"213","name":"Night Light","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"15478","sku":"1064373","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"1","stock_status":"In Stock","image":"data\/timeless-lighting\/15478-1050517-clear.png","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"4"}]},

{"category_id":"67","name":"DINING ROOM","sub_category":0,"product_total":"74","products":[
{"product_id":"248","name":"Amuse Bouche","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"28106","sku":"1056479","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"6","stock_status":"In Stock","image":"data\/dining\/28106-ambience.jpg","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"17"},
{"product_id":"239","name":"Amuse Bouche","description":"","meta_description":"","meta_keyword":"","tag":"","model":"25369","sku":"1050857","upc":"","ean":"","jan":"","isbn":"","mpn":"","location":"","quantity":"6","stock_status":"In Stock","image":"data\/dining\/25369-1050857-clear.png","manufacturer_id":null,"manufacturer":null,"price":"0.0000","special":null,"reward":"0","points":"0","tax_class_id":"0","weight_class_id":"1","length":"0.00000000","width":"0.00000000","height":"0.00000000","length_class_id":"1","subtract":"1","rating":0,"reviews":0,"minimum":"1","sort_order":"1","status":"1","viewed":"13"}
```

.
.
.

My code:

```
-(void)run{

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  for (NSDictionary *dict in [appDelegate.dic objectForKey:@"categories"]) {

      if (![dict[@"name"] isEqualToString:_subModel]) continue;

      for (NSDictionary *subcategory in [dict valueForKey:@"sub_category"])
      {
            if (![subcategory[@"name"] isEqualToString:_item]) continue;

            for (NSDictionary *product in subcategory[@"products"]) {

              //Update
              itemDetail *item = [[itemDetail alloc]init];
              item.strId = product[@"product_id"];
              item.strName = product[@"name"];
              item.strImage = product[@"image"];

              [_arrayItem addObject:product];

              NSLog(@"ITEM: %@", _arrayItem);
              //NSLog(@" %@, %@, %@", item.strId, item.strName, item.strImage);

              [_arraySubCategory addObject:product[@"name"]];
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a product object with name, image etc as its properties. Then add this object to your array.

```
.
.
.
for (NSDictionary *product in subcategory[@"products"]) {
          Product *product = [[Product alloc]init]; 
          product.name = product[@"name"];
          product.image = product[@"image"]; //and so on
          [_arraySubCategory addObject:product];
      }
```

Now when you want to get the data from your array,

```
for (Product *product in _arraySubCategory)
{
    if([product.name isEqualToString:@"abc"])
    {
       NSLog(@"%@",product.name);
      //do what you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean to create a NSObject file?

Comment: Yes. NSObject file will be the data model "Product".

Comment: you should better add productId property in product model. then compare with id not name. :)

Comment: Could you give me more detail @FawadMasud ?
I have created new NSObject and called `itemDetail` and properties with `id` `name` `image` as NSString. Now where would I copy your first code?

Comment: @FawadMasud _arraySubCategory  is `NSMutableArray`

Comment: My first code is copied from your code. I just added the lines in the loop. Look at "for (NSDictionary *product in subcategory[@"products"])" in your own code

Comment: Yes _arraySubCategory is mutable array.

Comment: @IrfanGul I will compare it to the id Thanks

Comment: @FawadMasud I have updated my code. but I have a small issue how to add item.strId, item.strName, item.strImage to the _arrayItem so I can check it?

Comment: Don't add product to _arrayItem. Add "item" instead. Then these values will be printed in NSLog. I have also updated second part of my answer in which you can print whatever you want to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70557/discussion-between-luai-kalkatawi-and-fawad-masud).